# How to get numer of objects/elements (Foreign Key) in template

Tags: python, django, django-models

how to get number of answers for question

```
class Answers(models.Model):
    ...
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='Question')
```

when I

```
return render_to_response('profile.xhtml',
                      {'questions': Question.objects.filter(author=details_profile),},
                      context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

and in template i wanna get number of answers for each question ({{ q.answer.count }} is just a example)

```
{% for q in questions %}
    {{ q.title }}, Answers: {{ q.answer.count }}
{% endfor %}
```

---

nvm i just make in models.py

```
class Question(models.Model):
    ...
    def count_it(self):
        return Answers.objects.filter(question=self).count()
```

and use in template {{ q.count_it }}

Answer (score 1):

If you hadn't set `related_name='Question'`, you'd be able to get the count in the template like this:

```
{{ q.answer_set.count }}
```

...because "answer_set" is the default `related_name`. As is, you should be able to use:

```
{{ q.Question.count }}
```

But that's ugly! Hopefully you've figured out by now that the `related_name` is the name you want to use to refer *back* to the current model *from* the model you're referencing in your `ForeignKey`. So the best option would be something like:

```
class Answers(models.Model):
    ...
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name='answers')
```

and then in the template:

```
{% for q in questions %}
    {{ q.title }}, Answers: {{ q.answers.count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{% for q in questions %}
    {{ q.title }}, Answers: {{ q.Question|length }}
{% endfor %}
```

I would recommend changing your related name there to something like 'answers' or something.

Comment: {{ q.Question|length }} give me 0 it is not true,
yeah I know, I have to rename,